# error: missing binary operator before token "("

Tags: c++, gcc, luabind

after gcc upgrade my project fails to build due to the error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp:31:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/back_reference.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:93,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/include/Scripting/ScriptManager.hpp:21,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/source/Core/Root.cpp:28:
/usr/include/luabind/detail/call_member.hpp:319:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/back_reference.hpp:27:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:93,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/include/Scripting/ScriptManager.hpp:21,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/source/Core/Root.cpp:28:
/usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp:92:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/function.hpp:10:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:94,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/include/Scripting/ScriptManager.hpp:21,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/source/Core/Root.cpp:28:
/usr/include/luabind/detail/call_function.hpp:326:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/detail/constructor.hpp:12:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:96,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/include/Scripting/ScriptManager.hpp:21,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/source/Core/Root.cpp:28:
/usr/include/luabind/wrapper_base.hpp:92:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from /usr/include/luabind/class.hpp:107:0,
                 from /usr/include/luabind/luabind.hpp:28,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/include/Scripting/ScriptManager.hpp:21,
                 from /home/ockonal/Workspace/themisto/engine/source/Core/Root.cpp:28:
/usr/include/luabind/detail/call_member.hpp:319:1: error: missing binary operator before token "("
```

What could it be? I've also tried latest gcc (4.8) snapshot but it didn't help.

p.s.

```
extra/boost 1.49.0-1 [installed]
core/gcc 4.6.3-1 (base-devel) [installed]
aurbuild/luabind 0.9.1-1 [installed]
```

Comment: Could you please provide minimal code around at least one of the cases for which the error is output?

Comment: @izomorphius the error isn't related to my code. I've removed luabind and downloaded latest stable release. I can't build it due to this errors in given files (from error output).

Comment: all these lines where you get an error are similar to `#elif BOOST_PP_ITERATION_FLAGS() == 1`

Comment: I have changed the summary of your question to make it easier to find it if one searches for the error.

Comment: And if your search arrives at this page, but you got this error without boost, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21338385/10396) for a more general explanation of the message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As luabind is present as a google [google project](http://code.google.com/p/papercrop/) I was able to browse the code and find which lines are causing the error. They all look like:

```
#elif BOOST_PP_ITERATION_FLAGS() == 1
```

It seems others have run into this problem and I found this [thread](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6631) that I hope will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe, you know how to fix it: `#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1 (4, (0, LUABIND_MAX_ARITY, <luabind/wrapper_base.hpp>, 1))` I have never worked with this macro from BOOST.

Comment: As far as I see it the guy simply changes an elif to else if and this seems to fix the problem. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: In wrapper_base.hpp, after adding `#else` and `#if` around line 93, you need to add an extra `#endif` at the end of the file.