# Preprocessor if in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-preprocessor

I had the following structure:

```
#if COND
  ...
#endif
#elif COND2
  ...
#else
  ...
#endif
```

I have to replace `elif` with two statements: `else` and `if`:

```
#if COND
  ...
#endif
#else
  #if COND2
     ...
  #endif
#else     // error: #else after #else
  ...
#endif
```

What's wrong?

p.s. No I see what's wrong but how to write it without errors?

Comment: You indeed have an `#else` after an `#else`.

Comment: Which error message did you get?

Comment: Why do you have to replace it in the first place? What’s the problem with the first version (well, except for the wrong `#endif`)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631762/missing-binary-operator-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two `#else` statements in the same `#if`.

The correct version would be:

```
#if COND
  ...
#else
  #if COND2
     ...
  #else
     ...
  #endif
#endif
```

Comment: Okay, I see that. But how to replace in my case?

Comment: @Ockonal actually, this version is the correct one. You also had an #endif before the first #else.